# Logarithm Trigonometric Equation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, logarithms

I am interested in solving the following question:
\begin{equation*}
\log _{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x))\times \log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x))=\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation*}
One approach that I tried was as follows; Let 
\begin{equation*}
\log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x))=p,~\log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x))=q.
\end{equation*}
This implies that $pq=1/4$. Using the fact that $\log_a b=c$ can be written as $a^c=b$, we have 
\begin{equation*}
\left(\sin(x)\cos(x)\right)^p=\sin(x),~\left(\sin(x)\cos(x)\right)^q=\cos(x).
\end{equation*}
Using the law $\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$, we can write
\begin{equation*}
1=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=(\sin(x)\cos(x))^{2p}+(\sin(x)\cos(x))^{\frac{1}{2p}}=\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation*}
however I am not sure what to do from here (or if this is even the correct approach). I also tried substituting the equation in Wolfram alpha as well as but both returned nothing of use to me. I will be grateful if anyone can help advance this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite using the natural logarithm,

$$\frac{\ln\sin x}{\ln(\sin x\cos x)}\frac{\ln\cos x}{\ln(\sin x\cos x)}=\frac14$$

or

$$(\ln\sin x+\ln\cos x)^2-4\ln\sin x\ln\cos x=0$$

or

$$(\ln\sin x-\ln\cos x)^2=0.$$

The rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

You are given that 
$$\log _{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x))\times \log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x))=\frac{1}{4}$$

You also know that 
$$\log _{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x)) + \log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x))=1$$

From here, you can find the difference of the two logs:

$$\left( \log _{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x)) - \log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x)) \right)^2\\=\left( \log _{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x)) + \log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x)) \right)^2\\-4 \log _{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x)) \log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x)) =0$$

**P.S.** If you are familiar with AM-GM inequality, here is a cute solution: Let $a=\log _{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\sin(x)), b= \log_{\sin(x)\cos(x)}(\cos(x))$. You know
$$a+b=1 \\
ab=\frac{1}{4}$$
Therefore, both numbers are positive, and by AM-GM we have
$$\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{1}{4}=\sqrt{ab} \leq \frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Therefore, we have equality in the AM-GM inequality and hence $a=b$.